# Postgraphile + express + jwt is throwing 'No authorization token found' even though graphiql works

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, graphql

I am trying to use the jwt express middleware as well as the postgraphile middleware together, and I want to add an exception for having an auth token to the graphiql interface. I know that postgraphile starts up graphql on `/graphql` and graphiql on `/graphiql` unless otherwise configured. So in my jwt middleware init I am doing this:

```
app.use(jwt({ secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET}).unless({path: ['/', /\/graphiql/i, /\/graphql/i, /auth/i]}));
```

Which makes it so `/graphiql`, `/graphql`, and `/auth` routes do not require an auth token. This appears to work fine because I can get to the graphiql interface just fine, and the graphql queries I'm building are working just fine. However, in my express terminal, there is still something that it's trying to connect to that is throwing a `No authorization token found` when I load http://localhost:3000/graphiql

Any thoughts on what else it might be trying to hit that I will also have to add to the `unless()` method in the JWT middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostGraphile currently loads the GraphiQL assets (JS, CSS) from `/_postgraphile/*`, so you probably want to whitelist those assets.

Another approach is to mount `postgraphile` *before* you add the `jwt` middleware - that way it will be unaffected by it and you won't need to maintain a `.unless` list.

```js
app.use(postgraphile(...));
app.use(jwt(...));
app.use(...);
```